# dc.js ignore results later than today

Tags: dc.js

In DC.JS I have a rowChart of Top 10 variance of A minus B with the following dim/group:

```
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(grp)
```

Relevant Variables are:

```
var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.DATE; });
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y");
```

For the group, this works fine:

```
var grp= dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return Math.abs(d.A - d.B);});
```

However, what I'd like to do is only show items that are up to today only.

I tried the function below but this is not working. It may just be syntax.
Any Ideas?

```
var grp2= dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
if (dateDim > dateFormat(today))return dateDim; else return Math.abs(d.A- B.plan);
```

Thanks, stutray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed in the dc.js FAQ: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-filter-the-data-before-its-charted

So ... originally I said the above. But what you actually want to do is filter out records that don't match a particular pre-defined filter so that they are not aggregated into your groups for this chart? In that case you need to use custom filter functions and I would recommend using a helper library like Reductio, which provides a filter function.

```
var dAct = reductio().filter(function(d) {
    // Here `d` is the actual data record. Return a boolean by testing
    // d against your filter criteria. Return true to include the record and
    // false to exclude it.
    return d.STARTDATE !== "10\/Sep\/2016";
  })
  .sum(function(d) {return Math.abs(d.A - d.B);})(dateDim.group());
```

If you use Reductio, you'll also need to use a valueAccessor function on your chart in dc.js:

```
rChart
  ...
  .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.value.sum; })
```

Updated example on Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxrPJv

Documentation: https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-reductio-b-filter-b-i-filterfn-i-

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. However i'm not quite understanding the construct. I hard-coded a date to test - var dateTestHere = ('20/05/2016') -  but this resulted in the error "dateTestHere is not a function" so I assume I need to build function to exclude the relevant date?

Comment: You just need to return a Boolean. You can do that by calling a function or just doing a test on the 'd' parameter and returning the result.

Comment: I've updated the example further to align to your data. You'll probably have to make further changes as the date format on your record may not match the date format in the test, but hopefully it gives the idea.

Comment: BTW - usually you'll get quicker and better answers if you put together a JSFiddle or Codepen where people working to answer your question can actually test their answers directly against your data.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how would I build that into the reductio method you gave. I tried this (although this returned NaN) var myGroup = reductio().filter(function(d) { if (d.key == "08/Apr/2016") return (d.key); else return ""; }) .sum(function(d) {return Math.abs(d.A - d.B);})(dateDim.group());

Comment: Appreciate the nod to Codepen. I'm still not getting anywhere (!) Here's the link: http://codepen.io/stutray/pen/KzjxPa

Comment: I've created an updated version of your Codepen that excludes one day (Sept 10) from the groups. However, if what you really want to do is drop groups and not exclude records from groups, see the FAQ about creating fake groups.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. This is great and working as expected. I tested <= "08\/Sep\/2016"; and it shows dates up to and including 8 Sep. I can see the real benefit of reductio. Grateful for your support and the library.

Comment: Great - Just be careful about how you are doing these string comparisons. "Feb" > "Mar" will evaluate to true. Better to convert to Date objects or compare YYYYMMDD formats.

Comment: Actually, my example was wrong. I shouldn't make up examples 5 min after I wake up :-) But you get the idea. :-)

Comment: Easily done. Pointed me in the right direction either way :)